# Flags, System.out.format Java

Tags: java, format, flags

Talking about flags, it's described in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) that the flag ' ' (empty space) will insert automatically an empty space instead of the sign "+" just at the beginning of the number.
However when I try it it works only when the first optional argument of the format specifier is filled.

```
  System.out.printf("% d%n %1$ d%n",0x3);
```

Even though there is an empty space in both the formatters, it works only in the latter one `%1$ d%n` whereas in the former `% d%n` the leading empty space meaning the positive number is absent (even though the flag ' ' is on).

Is there any specific reason why it happens like that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `System.out.printf("'% d'%n '%1$ d'%n", 0x3);` to see where your error is.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the output of that line of code:

```
 3
  3
```

Both lines have a leading space, however, the second line has two spaces because you have a space between the second and third conversion, i.e. if I split the `String` to make it more readable:

```
"% d" + "%n" + " " + "%1$ d" + "%n"
```